# View not passing data to the controller on submission of form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

When I use ViewModel in Create action the data traveled from view to controller but when I use Customer class instead of ViewModel my obj receive no data.

My Customer Model:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSubscribedToNewsletter { get; set; }

    public MembershipType MembershipTypes { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Membership Type")]
    public byte MembershiptypeId { get; set; }

    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

My MembershipType Model:

```
public class MembershipType
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public short SignUpFee { get; set; }
    public byte DurationInMonths { get; set; }
    public byte DiscountRate { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
 public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MembershipType> MembershipTypes { get; set; }

    public Customer Customerss { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Customer c)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Create", "Customers"))
{ <div class= "form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m=> m.Customerss.Name )
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customerss.Name, new {@class = "form-control" 
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.Customerss.IsSubscribedToNewsletter ) Subscribed To NewsLetter
    </label>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customerss.MembershiptypeId )
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customerss.MembershiptypeId ,new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes ,"Id","Name"),"Select Membership Type",  new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customerss.Id)


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Save </button>}
```

[Page Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSm0B.png)

Comment: Your view is still strongly typed to the view model. So the input element's names will not be maching with `Customer` property names (see the view source of the generated page)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What changes should I make in my View? Could you please elaborate a little bit more.

Comment: I have attached the page source.

Comment: I suggest you read about how model binding works.

Comment: I have read about Model Binding and tried to follow same steps as described on internet but unable to get around this problem, then I raised my question over here in hope of resolving the problem.